# Git "absolute" paths pipe between commands?

Tags: git

I am in some directory of my git working tree and run `git diff HEAD`. This will show the filenames starting from the repo root (actually prefix them with a/ but for example `--name-only` takes care of at least that). These paths then are directly unusable with say `git checkout` or `git add` because those expect relative paths. Is there an option that tells these commands that a certain path is from the repository root?

Answer (score 2):

git diff HEAD --name-only **--relative $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)**

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to make an alias out of this, even tried `adiff  = "!f() { git diff HEAD --no-prefix --relative $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) $@; }; f"` but  the relative part doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I see, you could `cd` to the repo root and then `cd -` to get back to where you were?